# The number one "1" key not working in terminal and iTerm2

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, iterm2

My number one key is not entering nor can it be pasted into the terminal. It just makes the 'ping' sound when pressed. 
I followed [this question's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39696/why-does-terminal-ignore-capital-b?newreg=86e8a12e004b4901a072c008d57351b7) answer, which his problem was the exact same as mine, but the result is still the same.

When I ran `bind -p`, the result:

```
"-": self-insert
".": self-insert
"/": self-insert
"0": self-insert
"2": self-insert
"3": self-insert
"4": self-insert
"5": self-insert
```

I ran `bind -p > ~/.inputrc` and edited the file to include the key. Which is now like:

```
"-": self-insert
".": self-insert
"/": self-insert
"0": self-insert
"1": self-insert
"2": self-insert
"3": self-insert
"4": self-insert
"5": self-insert
```

I restarted both my computer and the terminal and iTerm, and the result is still the same.

`bind -p` still shows the same result as earlier

Comment: Run `bash -l -x` to start a login shell in trace mode; the output should lead you to the file that is running a command that unbinds the 1 key.

Comment: I'm not sure what to look for in the output. Are there any keywords or symbols to look for?

Comment: Probably a call to `bind -r 1`.